# Table with 50 million data and adding index takes too much time

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, query-optimization

I was working on table which has near about 50 million data(2GB-size). I had requirement to optimize the performance. So when I add index on column through phpmyadmin panel, table got lock and result in holding up all queries in queue on that table and ultimately results in restart/kill all queries. (And yeah, I forgot to mention I was doing this on production. My bad!)

When I did some research I found out some solution like creating duplicate table but any alternative method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow this steps,

1. Create a temp table
2. Creates triggers on the first table (for
   inserts, updates, deletes) so that they are replicated to the temp
   table
3. In small batches, migrate data When done, rename table to new
   table, and drop the other table

But as you said you are doing it in production then you need to consider live traffic while dropping a table and creating another one

Comment: yeah, I can. I will try once again

Comment: Better yet, use `pt-online-schema-change`; it automates all that for you.